# Sample mean of standard normal variate follows Normal

Tags: probability

Let $X_i$ , $i = 1$ to $n$ be i.i.d standard normal variate. Show that $Y$ follows $N(0,1/n)$ where $Y$is mean of $X_i$

Comment: I was trying to just calculate mean of these i.i.d and tried representing it in the form N(0,1/n) but was unsuccesful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moment generating function of normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is $$\exp\left(t\mu+\frac{1}{2}t^2\sigma^2\right)$$

Now let's compute the moment generating function of $Y$.
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[exp(tY)]&=\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{t}{n}X_i\right)\right]\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left( \frac{t}{n}X_i\right)\right]\\
&=\left[\exp\left( \frac{1}{2}\frac{t^2}{n^2}\right) \right]^n\\
&=\exp\left( \frac{1}{2}\frac{t^2}{n}\right)
\end{align*}

Hence $Y \sim N(0,\frac{1}{n}).$

Comment: a lot of thanks.